# How to start contributing to JHipster

Tags: java, spring, open-source, jhipster

I would like to learn in deep about Spring components and I found out that JHipster is an open source project that uses It.

When I entered this page: https://github.com/jhipster, I saw that there are 69 repositories and I got lost.

From which of them should I start to contribute to code Spring frameworks along Java? How can I talk to them to show I am available.

In case anyone knows another good project that is open source and uses Spring and Java I would appreciate also.

Notice, I already know the basics from Java 8 and would like to improve and get more competitive professionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contributions are welcome.
Please read [instructions on how to contribute](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)

Most of these 69 projects are generated apps, so they don't count.
The main project is the generator: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster

On github propose your help on an existing issue or create a feature request and propose to implement it.

You can also improve documentation at https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster.github.io